# Need to bold cells where the formula result is greater than or equal to 10 via VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need to apply **bold** to all cells within a certain range where the formula result is 10 or more. I've tried the following code but it seems to apply bold randomly!

```
Sub BoldHighHours()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c As Object

For Each c In Range("I7:AM1005")
   If c.Value >= 10 Then
       c.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = True
       c.Offset(0, 2).Font.Bold = True
   Else
       c.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = False
       c.Offset(0, 2).Font.Bold = False
   End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you've been following my previous questions/saga you'll understand why I can't use conditional formatting! Autofilter doth not look kindly upon large amounts of conditional formatting and punishes ye with slowdown greatly!

Comment: generally, code looks fine. Do you understand what `.Offset(x,y)` do? Do you use it intentionally?

Comment: So, to clarify your logic, you are looping through some 31000 cells and setting formats of the two cells next to it? Now, if J10.value is >10, then K10 and L10 are bold. next, it looks at K10 and if K10.value>10, then L10 and M10 are bold, next it looks at L10, and if L10.value>10, then M10 and N10 are bold ... and so on... wow...and that is quicker and more efficient than using Conditional Formatting?

Comment: surely you could speed up your Autofilter by using Sort first?

Comment: Are you sure you want to loop through all columns `I` to `AM`, and **then** bold the right 2 cells?this doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Please tell us what you need to achieve because your code is certainly not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `Offset()`:

```
Sub BoldHighHours()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Dim c As Range 

    For Each c In Range("I7:AM1005") 

        If c.Value >= 10 Then 
            c.Font.Bold = True
        Else 
            c.Font.Bold = False 
        End If 

    Next 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

**my optimisation:**

```
Sub BoldHighHours()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Dim c As Long

    For Each c = 9 to 39 ' hopefully i to am..

        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

        With Range("A8:A1005").Offset(0, c - 1)

            .Font.Bold = False
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=10"
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With 

    Next 

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: there must be a better option than 31000 operations...?

Comment: @Philip, 31k is nothing, check this 2.5 billion one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830617/excel-vba-find-all

Comment: another situation where ADO and SQL can make a big problem so much smaller!

Comment: +1 nice work! I am currently trying to reduce the 2.5 Billion one down by a factor of maybe 1000!

Comment: well, in fact if the OP can use a formula on the sheet, it can be only a few thousand, otherwise, using ADO and OLE DB is the way to go, reducing it to just a couple of operations using a SQL Query and *CopyFromRecordset*

Comment: 2.5 billion? Holy guacamole! Anyway, sorry yes I cannibalised the code from elsewhere on the internet and didn't realise the offset function was COMPLETELY not needed. Your optimisation is amazing!! I'm slowly beginning to see the massive potential in using Range If and Else! Why the hell didn't I find this site lonnnng ago??

Comment: here are some other sites for you: [Chip Pearson Excel MVP](http://www.cpearson.com) and [Charley kyd Excel MVP](http://www.exceluser.com) and [Ron de Bruin Excel MVP Legend](http://www.rondebruin.nl) and [Colo MVP Excel Legend](http://www.mrexcel.com) and of course, who could forget [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com) or *the genius of all genius's* [All Experts - Mr Tom Ogilvy](http://www.allexperts.com/ep/1059-2697/Excel/Tom-Ogilvy.htm)

Comment: here are some other sites for you: [Mr McGimpsey & friends](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/index.html) [Excel Author MVP Mr Ron Bovey](http://www.appspro.com/Tips/Tips_And_Tricks.htm) and [Mr Spreadsheet Himself - John Walkenbach](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tips)

Comment: Thank you for all your help  :)   I shall investigate the links you've provided